# Why does Chrome's Incognito mode retrieve resources faster than the normal mode?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, browser

I tested this from multiple machines (desktops and laptops) and OSes (Windows and Mac), and I can replicate the same behavior:
**Resources are downloaded much faster in Incognito mode** (not the rendering speed)

I could roughly think of two conditions under which Incognito and normal modes can be faster respectively:

- Incognito mode can be faster because it has no extensions.
- Normal mode can be faster because it caches the resource.

So I disabled all my extensions in normal mode and "reset" all the settings which deleted cache and browsing history, etc.

In all cases, when I looked at the Chrome inspector, resources are downloaded much faster in Incognito mode than in normal mode. Links load blazingly fast in Incognito mode.

Why is this a case?

Comment: By default, Incognito mode does not load your Chrome extensions.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing. Have you been able to find the answer? The same thing happens when in a Chrome extension I test `chrome-extension://<id>/index.html` versus a file from `a web url/file system/or localhost`. The former loads blazingly fast, same as in the incognito mode. But all other methods are noticeably slower, which is very strange (of course I tested with the same amount of extensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be a caching problem.
The same was also mentioned here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0JRiv4Pyb8uE/?hl=no

[Why does an incognito tab load a website much faster than a site opened normal tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578495/why-does-an-incognito-tab-load-a-website-much-faster-than-a-site-opened-normal-t)

I was able to achieve the same loading speed without the incognito mode by using this answer: [Disable cache Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725712/disable-cache-chrome-extension) (I made it work for all urls `urls: ["<all_urls>"]`)

Disabling cache with `webRequest` has made it as fast as in the incognito mode.

Update: now with new hardware and an SSD it doesn't seem to make a difference for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this question. 
Apparently, clearing up cache and browser history through Chrome's Setting and disabling extensions through `chrome://extensions` is not enough.

If you're on macOS, type the command below (from https://superuser.com/a/318205):

```
rm -r /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/Google\ Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.google.Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.google.Chrome.savedState/
rm ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Actives/com.google.Chrome
rm ~/Library/Google/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Speech/Speakable\ Items/Application\ Speakable\ Items/Google\ Chrome/
```

And then the cache will be completely cleared. Even after that, Incognito mode seems to be faster but it significantly increased the download speed of normal mode.

EDIT: I've unselected my answer because this did not solve the problem. After a few days, it slowed down again and without a proper benchmark, I'm not sure whether this had solved the problem in the first place.