# Disable cache Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I made a plugin that loads a handful of pages of my game website, but I'd like it to also disable the cache as it loads. I can only find [cache disabling during reloading](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload). I could load the page, then reload it every time, but that seems not ideal. Is there some way I could disable the cache for my generated tabs, either by the tabs themselves or even the domain.

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest API to modify outgoing request's cache-control headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What wOxxOm said is correct, using the webRequest API I could modify the cache-control headers. I needed to make a background script with this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function (details) {
    var headers = details.requestHeaders || [];
    headers.push({
        "name": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache"
    });
    return {requestHeaders: headers};
},
{
    urls: [
        "*://test.domain.tv/*",
        "*://domain.tv/*"
    ]
},
[]
);
```

I also had to add "webRequest" to my manifest.