# Why does an incognito tab load a website much faster than a site opened normal tab?

Tags: google-chrome, web

A website opened in an incognito tab loads much faster than a website, which has been opened in a "normal" chrome tab: This is not only a feeling, but network checks in the chrome developers tools proof that.

How does chrome load the website faster in incognito mode?

Comment: Incognito mode supposedly creates a temporary storage of information, almost like a virtual machine, so I'd imagine a lot of the bloat that's piled up on normal chrome, isn't there and isn't loaded. Unless set to active in incognito, I believe apps are off by default.

Comment: Already been asked here too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021971/why-does-chromes-incognito-mode-retrieve-resources-faster-than-the-normal-mode). By default Incognito does not load your Chrome extensions. I guess that would speed it up somewhat.