# Chrome very slow to start video stream

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I am doing a bunch of HTML5 video tests, trying to get the videos playing/streaming as fast as possible. For the most part, they start immediately on Safari and FireFox, however they take much longer on Google Chrome. I thought it was something in my code, but then I tried the direct video link and got the same results. From an empty cache, Safari and Firefox start just about instantly. Chrome is taking a full 30-40 seconds, which is obviously way too long. Am I missing something here? Here is the video link I'm testing: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/web/documentation/TemplateDocumentation/video_files/IN_Intro-800.mp4

Comment: Does it work faster in **Incognito** mode? PS: the video loads okay (3 secs or less) for me, so there is something clogging up your Chrome (or maybe even slowing the internet speed?). If Incognito mode works then it you might have to delete some cookies, empty cache, etc...

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the problem. I have cleared all data, cookies cache etc. but same issue. But as you suggested, Incognito it works great. Any ideas here? maybe I do a clean install - but I'd still like to know what is causing the bottleneck

Comment: Right now I can only think of an Extension being the problem. Is there anything that can be disabled at `chrome://extensions/` for you? I found this [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021971/why-does-chromes-incognito-mode-retrieve-resources-faster-than-the-normal-mode) and its Answers also mention that disabling cache and stopping extensions made it work faster for them.

Comment: Got it. It was an extension. I should have tested that first. Im not sure what one it was yet, but after disabling all extensions, its super fast. really appreciate the help/insight

Comment: Glad it's sorted now. Though I'm a little annoyed to hear that the browser clean-up didn't fix the issue (all that byte-damn deleting was for nothing!! Grr...). PS: Did videos on other sites like Youtube play normally (_ie:_ only the video link you posted was troublesome)? If yes, I wonder why the extension and that MP4's server were not playing nice together.

Comment: Actually upon more testing, everything was really slow, including large image loads. I don't normally use Chrome, so I figured it was just a browser issue, but with 30-40sec vid loads, I realized something else was up. Turns out I had ZenMate VPN installed and running, and didn't realize. That was the problem. Should have realized.

Answer (score 2):

I get near-instant playback in chrome. Below are 3 screenshots below (well, now links; can't embed images due to reputation requirements).

Chrome Dev Tool's **media** tool events showing timing for events relevant to the media player; its nascence to the end of video, information/properties of the player, and information/properties of the video track itself.

Do you have any custom settings in Chrome (pertaining to video decoding or video media in general) that are notably different from what you have set for Safari and/ or Firefox?

Additionally if you've enabled flags related to experimental javascript, HTML elements, and/ or video decoding/ encoding, you might want to  audit such settings. Other things like plugins, (Chrome) apps, etc. might have an effect.

Listed below are good places to have a look at in general:

- `chrome://version/`
- `chrome://flags/`
- `chrome://extensions/`
- `chrome://about/`

If you could provide an info regarding your build of Chrome, that would help a lot. I'm assuming this isn't related to your code because you've mentioned requesting the video asset directly in browser via the URL as hosted at [www.nlm.nih.gov](http://www.nlm.nih.gov) but if you've decided/discovered otherwise, any info regarding that would be good too.

[Event Timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knEEV.png)

[Player Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9LF9.png)

[Video Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9LD4.png)

Comment: Thank you! I'll test again tomorrow and update here. Appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Turns out I had ZenMate VPN installed and running, and didn't realize. My bad

Comment: No worries, happy to hear you worked out the issue.